# How can I deploy nextjs project with dynamic routes to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have created dynamic routes in my nextjs project. I want to upload it to firebase hosting. I set getStaticProps fallback:true and revalidate to 60. When I want to export, the export feature does not work because of these settings. When I use the deploy feature, it uploads the out or public folders to the hosting. How can I make this possible? Or is it possible for me to do what I want? Honestly, I couldn't find many resources. Thank you from now.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is deploy your app through `next export` with Incremental Static Regeneration (`fallback:true` and `revalidate`) then that's not possible. `next export` does not support all Next.js features, see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features.

Comment: Is there a way to have firebase hosting accept the code I designed without using the next export feature?

Comment: This video states that next js app are now supported https://youtu.be/i0VNBvCqpgI